Next js build time too long
I bought a template built on Nextjs 13 and I found that the build time is too long
The server take too much time to build components or pages
even I am not doing any request or fetching from an api
There is just the UI rendering
using  navigating between pages take long time to render pages


can anyone help me please!

Too long? How long do you expect it to take?

I added 2 screenshot with the question check them

May you add more detail? What do the screenshots show? What's the difference in code between the two screenshots?

I have run the app 2 times and take screenshot of the terminal showing time taken for building
There is no difference between the 2 screenshots I didn't change anything in the code
Building take too much time when the app start
and when navigating between pages with  got the same problem

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
